# VB.NET with Word - how to modify a paragraph indent after find

Tags: vb.net, formatting, ms-word, replace, indentation

I am using VB.NET (VS2012) and Word (2013) with the Word 14 interop. Note: I am NOT using VBA within Word and can't use that as a solution.

I am trying to do a search and replace in the document for all instances of a key value pair and can do this easily with a `Word.Document.Find.Execute()` command.

However, what I also need to do is adjust the `LeftIndent` of the paragraph where the word is located because the replacement text is larger (eg "XXXXXXXXXX") than the text it is replacing (eg "XXXXX") and the area isn't large enough.

So I have been trying the following, but the paragraph indent is just not changing. Note: `dicWords` is just a Dictionary with my find/replace words.

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word

' Open Word document
Dim WordApp As New Application
Dim WordDoc As Document = WordApp.Documents.Open(WordFile.FullName, False, True, False)

' Loop through the dictionary of parts and find/replace
Dim pair As KeyValuePair(Of String, String)
For Each pair In dicWords

    ' Replace text
    Dim bFound As Boolean = False
    Do
        ' Do Search
        bFound = WordDoc.Content.Find.Execute(FindText:=pair.Key, ReplaceWith:=pair.Value, Replace:=WdReplace.wdReplaceOne, Wrap:=WdFindWrap.wdFindContinue)
        If bFound = True Then
            ' The range should be set from above Find, so now set the LeftIndent
            WordDoc.Content.ParagraphFormat.LeftIndent = 5
        End If

    Loop While bFound = True

Next
```

However, the above isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
WordDoc.Selection.Range.ParagraphFormat.LeftIndent = 5
```